# How to install fish in a remote server I cannot sudo?

Tags: linux, software-installation, non-root-user, fish

I want to install the fish shell in a remote server I have no sudo privileges at, so that I can use it whenever I ssh.

Comment: I am sure you have tried this, but as a systems administrator I encourage all our users to definitely ask us first about installing it as a system package - we are often happy to do so (though I can't speak for your administrator), and if we aren't we should be able to give you an explanation for why you shouldn't put it in your home directory either.

Comment: @Zanchey The thing is that unfortunately I use just a simple guest account at the cluster and I didn't know if I should really bother the admin for something like that before trying it myself. Now that I reached a dead end due to a missing  `curses` dependency  I probably will though, I find `fish` a huge quality of life improvement.

Answer (score 6):

You would install it in your home directory.

To do that, you would check out the source repository of the `fish` shell from GitHub, and then follow the installation instructions under the section "Building" in [the `README.md` file](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/README.md#building), while telling CMake that you'd like to use an alternative installation directory:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell
cd fish-shell

mkdir build
cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/local ..

make
make install
```

This would install `fish` and its associated files under `$HOME/local`.  The `fish` executable would be located in `$HOME/local/bin` (which you may want to add to your `$PATH`).

This obviously assumes that all the needed tools (`git`, `make`, `cmake` etc.) are available and that the build system finds all needed dependencies<sup>1</sup>.

To check out a particular release tag, for example `3.0.2` (the most recent release at the time of writing), use  `git clone --branch=3.0.2 --depth=1 ...` when cloning the repository.  If you don't specify a release tag, you will get the latest unstable development version of the code.

You then would have to make your ordinary shell start `fish` whenever it starts an interactive shell (assuming you don't want to start `fish` manually).  If your shell is `bash`, you could do that by adding

```
if [ -x "$HOME/local/bin/fish" ]; then
    exec "$HOME/local/bin/fish"
fi
```

or something similar to `$HOME/.bashrc`.  This particular way of doing it would *replace* the `bash` process with a `fish` process every time an interactive `bash` shell was started.

<sup>1</sup><sub>On some non-Linux systems, you would also have to manually patch `src/fallback.cpp` so that the `locale.h` header is included. Otherwise, that file may fail to compile due to `uselocale()` not being declared.  This is [a confirm bug in the code](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5753), which will be fixed in release 3.1.0 thanks to this question.</sub>

---

The other option is, as always, to talk to the administrator of the system and get *them* to install it from a pre-compiled package.  You would then be able to change your login shell to `fish` using `chsh` or whatever similar command is available on the system.

Comment: I prefer the use of `.local` instead of `local`

Comment: @WeijunZhou Whatever floats your boat. I personally use `$HOME/local/stow/package-name` and then GNU `stow`.  I think `pip` (Python thing) uses `$HOME/.local` so I don't really want to put my own stuff in there among the Python things I've installed.

Comment: If you want it to run at login, you'd need to inject an `exec $HOME/local/bin/fish -l` in your current startup script, likely `.bash_profile`, `.profile` (ksh and sh), or `.login` (csh and tcsh).

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm trying to do what you said however I encountered another issue. My cmake version is 2.8.11 and fish requires 3.2, how do I upgrade without sudo? Is it doable?

Comment: @CoolCookie Well, you could jump down the rabbit hole and try to download and install `cmake` from sources as well (this is not the place for a tutorial about how to do that though), or you could bite the bullet and go and talk to the admin of that system.

Comment: @CoolCookie Either compile `cmake` yourself, or find an older version of `fish`. It is also possible to directly edit the `CMakeLists.txt` to bypass the check but it is not suggested.

Comment: @WeijunZhou This is getting ridiculous, I tried installing cmake 3.12.3 and I got  make[2]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/LIBCURL] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeFiles/LIBCURL.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: If you really want to compile `cmake` you may ask a new question with the full error message attached. Check for duplicates first though.

Comment: I strongly recommend against the use of `git clone --depth 1`, because fish will not know what version it is and you will run into trouble looking for help. Use a tarball instead (which is better for day-to-day use).

Comment: @Zanchey `fish --version` will return a Git commit hash if the code was compiled from an untagged revision.  Using this in a bug report etc. would pose no issue to the developers (as it's easy to check it out based on the hash). But I'll consider adding a note about using a specific release tag.

Comment: @Kusalananda There is a problem, when I hit `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/local ..` I get the following error,  `CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CURSES_CURSES_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "fishlib" in directory /home/fish-shell-master

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
`. Any suggestions? I installed cmake 3.3.0.

Comment: @CoolCookie The `fish` shell requires the `curses` or `ncurses` library to run.  These (or one of them) is probably already installed on the system, but to _compile_ anything against it, you will need the corresponding header files etc. (this is sometimes available as a separate `*-dev` or `*-devel` package on Linux).  In short, you've hit a missing dependency.

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh I see, do you know what should I do in this case? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @CoolCookie I'm sorry, I'm not a Linux user and I've never had to compile `curses` from e.g. https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/#downloads My OpenBSD system has the required files by default. A comment section like this is not really ideal for doing a tutorial. Again, it would be simpler to get in contact with the admin of that remote system and have them update it with the software that you require.

Comment: @Kusalananda Okay I understand, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Install software rootlessly is a typical problem, and there are many solutions.
For kernel version<3.X, I only recommend [linuxbrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew), just `brew install fish` deal with its dependencies like cmake.
For higher, see [awesome-linux-containers](https://github.com/Friz-zy/awesome-linux-containers)